# removing randomness from capybara feature test

Tags: rspec, capybara, stubbing

I am making a simple game of Rock, paper, scissors using a Sinatra and testing with rspec-capybara. The game plays against a computer opponent that randomizes either rock, paper or scissor. I am writing a test for the web page result. I am stubbing the opponent response to always choose paper so that the player loses(because he selects rock)

```
scenario "Player chooses rock, and the computer chooses paper." do
single_player_sign_in_and_play
click_button('rock')
allow(game).to receive_message_chain(:player2, :weapon) {:paper}
allow(game).to receive(:outcome).and_return("You lose!")
allow(game).to receive(:message).and_return("Your opponent chose #{game.player2.weapon}. #{game.outcome}")
expect(page).to have_content("Your opponent chose paper. You lose!")
```

end

I want the opponent to always have :paper as a weapon so the player loses: The page should have content: "Your opponent chose paper. you lose!"

Comment: This still returns random behaviour from the opponent!

Comment: what do you want to achieve? it's not clear

Comment: I want the opponent to always have :paper as a weapon so the player loses: The page should have content:

Answer (score 0):

You should stub calls before calling `click_button('rock')`

```
scenario "Player chooses rock, and the computer chooses paper." do
  allow(game).to receive_message_chain(:player2, :weapon) {:paper}
  allow(game).to receive(:outcome).and_return("You lose!")
  allow(game).to receive(:message).and_return("Your opponent chose paper. You lose!")
  single_player_sign_in_and_play
  click_button('rock')
  expect(page).to have_content(game.message)
end
```

I would recommend to not use `game.message` in expectation and use `Your opponent chose paper. You lose!` instead. You can also consider moving stubbing to `before` block

Answer (score 0):

Doubles cannot be passed into Capybara feature tests. Doubles should only be used in unit tests! The following code passes.

```
scenario "Player chooses rock, and the computer chooses paper." do
allow_any_instance_of(Opponent).to receive(:weapon).and_return(:paper)
single_player_sign_in_and_play
click_button('rock')
save_and_open_page
expect(page).to have_content("Your opponent chose paper. You lose!")
```

end